# Too many versions of Ruby in my app - which one are really necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have a ruby on rails 7 app so I have ruby listed in my gemfile.

**app/Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "~> 3.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.0"
```

But beyond the "standard" Rails app, i'm leveraging a Dockerfile with docker-compose to build a docker container as I'm using [Github Codespace](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces). I'm pretty beginner with docker so i more or less used the boilerplate provided by microsoft which starts like this:

```
# # [Choice] Ruby version (use -bullseye variants on local arm64/Apple Silicon): 3, 3.1, 3.0, 2, 2.7, 2.6, 3-bullseye, 3.1-bullseye, 3.0-bullseye, 2-bullseye, 2.7-bullseye, 2.6-bullseye, 3-buster, 3.1-buster, 3.0-buster, 2-buster, 2.7-buster, 2.6-buster
ARG VARIANT=3.1-bullseye
# Note the images provided by Microsoft have some pre-installed packages
# to make them work out of the box for dev container feature
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/ruby:0-${VARIANT}
```

But then I added also to manage versions of ruby and other libraries a Version manager called [ASDF](https://asdf-vm.com/) so a bit futher down on the same dockerfile, it reads:

```
# # Environment variables
ARG RUBY_VERSION latest

RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git $HOME/.asdf && \
    echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo '. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> $HOME/.profile
# ASDF steps: install asdf ruby plugin, then a ruby version, then set our machine e.g our container's global Ruby version
RUN bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc  && 
    asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git &&
    asdf install ruby $RUBY_VERSION &&
    asdf global ruby $RUBY_VERSION"
```

So in total that's like 3 places where I think there is Ruby that gets installed. I feel it's too much and not really a good practice. Should I remove ruby from my gemfile and at the toip to only keep ASDF ruby as this is the tool i manage ruby versions with?

Should I keep two of them? What is recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually should not use a version manager with Docker (`asdf`, `rbenv`, `rvm`, ...).  At a mechanical level, most paths to running a Docker container don't read the `.bashrc` or `.profile` files you set up, and you need a pretty roundabout path to "activate" the version manager.  Style-wise, the Docker image contains only a single application and its runtime, so you'll only ever need a single Ruby version within the context of its container, and the image's `FROM` line is enough.

You should keep the `ruby` constraint in your Gemfile, which helps ensure you have a compatible version of Ruby in other environments (for example, using `asdf` in your non-Docker desktop setup).  And you need a Ruby version in your image's `FROM` line so Docker knows which base image to use.

In your example, without installing or invoking `asdf`, the base image already has Ruby 3.1 available, so you don't need to do any additional work to (re)install it.

Comment: Seems to make sense but newbie question: I guess using a version manager such as ASDF is cool for debugging, you cna just switch from ruby X to ruby Y version for example to see how your app behaves . 
If I don't use ASDF, how do I efficiently do that? do you just change in the dockerfile the ruby version ARG VARIANT={verison i want to switch to for debugging}, then relaunch the container, see how this behaves, then go back if required to initial version?
Is that the flow?

Comment: thanks again. Any insight in the related consequence of your answer?

Comment: Using a Dockerfile `ARG` to control the language version makes sense; and yes, you'd have to rebuild image and recreate the container if you changed this.